# Checking for a logged user

Tags: python, logging

I have two classes with similar first checking codes, but different behaviors. I suppose there is a way to refactor the code, so I don't need to retype it every time.  Is it possible to refactor this, or I must retype this code every time?

```
# Get actual logged user
user, msg = checkLoggedUser()
if user:
    self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
else:
```

The code is simple. Forget about my way to render the page, is a method over my own `PageHandler` class that works.

```
# Check for actual logged user
def checkLoggedUser():
    # Get actual logged user
    user = users.get_current_user()

    # Don't allow to register for a logged user
    if user:
        return True, "You are already logged in."
    else:
        return False, None

# Get and post for the login page
class Login(custom.PageHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Get actual logged user
        user, msg = checkLoggedUser()
        if user:
            self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
        else:
            self.renderPage('login.htm')

    def post(self):
        # Get actual logged user
        user, msg = checkLoggedUser()
        if user:
            self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
        else:
            # Make the login
            # bla, bla bla... code for login the user.

# Get and post for the register page
class Register(custom.PageHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Get actual logged user
        user, msg = checkLoggedUser()
        if user:
            self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
        else:
            self.renderPage("registerUser.htm")

    def post(self):
        # Get actual logged user
        user, msg = checkLoggedUser()
        if user:
            self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
        else:
            # Store in vars the form values
            # bla, bla bla... code for register the user.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class

```
class MyPageHandler(custom.PageHandler):
     def veryUserNotLoggedIn(self):
         if users.getCurrentUser():
             self.renderPage("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=msg)
             return False
         else:
             return True
```

Then you can write you class like

```
class Login(MyPageHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.verifyUserNotLoggedIn():
             self.renderPage('login.htm')
```

Comment: you are a number one! :) 2 refactors, 2 new knowledges for me. Thank you a lot (I'm a little rusty, I come from VB6... but learning a lot now).